# Cursor Loop in a PL/SQL Procedure that updates data

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql, database-cursor

I'm currently trying to learn PL/SQL. Right now I'm trying to understand how can I use cursor loop in a procedure that updates data.

Example scenario: Create a PROCEDURE, to update the `schedule_code` column to `A` using cursor loop. Update only the employee no `(100,300,500,700)`.

Here's the table I'm using for this test:

[image]

And this is the procedure I've created:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE p_upd_schdcde AS 
  CURSOR c1 
  IS 
    SELECT 'A' as schedule_code 
      FROM employee 
     WHERE employee_no IN (100,300,500,700);

BEGIN 
    FOR rec IN c1 
    LOOP
        UPDATE employee
          SET schedule_code = rec.schedule_code;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, happy learning, but I can't see the question. Btw, do you really think of needing a procedure or a PL/SQL block rather than using a single update statement, and even need of putting a constant value in a loop. Of course you shouldn't forget to add a `commit` to the end whenever you call the procedure.

Comment: Moreover, it's far better to prepare the data along insert statements in text format, preferable within a fiddle such as in [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wh4zpMKJ) instead of sharing as image(s) to help people who will answer your question(s).

Comment: FYI, if your PL/SQL logic isn't doing anything with the data inside the `LOOP`...`END LOOP` block, you wouldn't normally use a cursor like this at all to do such an update. At high volumes, it forces too much context switching between the separate PL/SQL engine and SQL engine, and also requires single-row update operations which add execution overhead to each row.  It also prevents the use of parallelism. At low volumes this isn't a problem, but with big data it wouldn't scale. Just something to keep in mind. We use PL/SQL where needed, preferring pure SQL where we can.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, thank you! I agree with you that for this I can just use a simple UPDATE statement. However, my goal here is to understand how a pl/sql behaves and so even with a few data I want to test this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

In your procedure, you're updating all rows in a table because there's no `where` clause which would instruct Oracle *which* rows to update. Cursor should have selected IDs, not code.

Have a look at the following options.

Sample table, simplified (as other columns are irrelevant in this case):

```
SQL> select * from employee;

EMPLOYEE_NO S
----------- -
        100 X
        200 Y
        300 Z
```

**Option 1:**

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_upd_schdcde as
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select employee_no
  4                  from employee
  5                  where employee_no in (100, 300, 500, 700)
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      update employee set
  9        schedule_code = 'A'
 10        where employee_no = cur_r.employee_no;
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_upd_schdcde;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from employee;

EMPLOYEE_NO S
----------- -
        100 A
        200 Y
        300 A

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.
```

**Option 2:**

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_upd_schdcde as
  2    cursor c1 is
  3      select employee_no
  4      from employee
  5      where employee_no in (100, 300, 500, 700)
  6      for update;
  7    c1r c1%rowtype;
  8  begin
  9    open c1;
 10    loop
 11      fetch c1 into c1r;
 12      exit when c1%notfound;
 13      update employee set
 14        schedule_code = 'A'
 15        where current of c1;
 16    end loop;
 17    close c1;
 18  end;
 19  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_upd_schdcde;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from employee;

EMPLOYEE_NO S
----------- -
        100 A
        200 Y
        300 A

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL>
```

---

There are other variations, but - as you're learning PL/SQL, that should get you started.

Certainly, as Barbaros commented, normally we'd just `update` table at SQL level and wouldn't use PL/SQL at all. Though, if you don't try it, how will you ever learn PL/SQL so - go for it & enjoy.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! And yes, even though I know a simple SQL statement can handle this, I still want to use PL/SQL for learning purposes because how will I know I don't try.